# Laravel | Unable to get the search results filtered for *multiple keywords* | Returns all from the table now

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

Code(Controller):

```php
public function index(Request $request) {
    try {
        
        $this->productRepository->pushCriteria(new RequestCriteria($request));
        $this->productRepository->pushCriteria(new LimitOffsetCriteria($request));
        $this->productRepository->pushCriteria(new ProductsOfFieldsCriteria($request));
        
        if ($request->get('trending', null) == 'week') {
            $this->productRepository->pushCriteria(new TrendingWeekCriteria($request));
        } else {
            $this->productRepository->pushCriteria(new NearCriteria($request));
        }
        
        $queryString = $request->query;
        if ($queryString = $request->query('search')) {
            //     [$column, $term] = explode(':', $queryString);
            $terms = explode(" ", request('q'));
            $products = Product::query()->whereHas('store', function ($query) use ($terms) {
                foreach ($terms as $term) {
                    // Loop over the terms and do a search for each.
                    $query->where('name', 'like', '%' . $term . '%');
                }
            })->get();
        } else {
            $products = $this->productRepository->all();
        }
    }
    catch(RepositoryException $e) {
        return $this->sendError($e->getMessage());
    }
        
    return $this->sendResponse($products->toArray(), 'Products retrieved successfully');
}
```

I'm getting the complete set of data within the `product` table as of now. My intension is to be able to filter the results with matching keywords as in `$terms` . Can someone please help figure out what's missing in filtering above ?

Comment: Is your query parameter `search` or is it `q`?

Comment: Also shouldn't it be `Product::whereHas`? Maybe it's the same though (I'm not exactly familiar with Laravel).

Comment: Hi My search is for q. Its going to be set of search strings...Product::whereHas appears to be the same

Comment: Did you check the contents of `terms`? Did you check the produced query with `->toSql()` on the query builder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't get much help around & solved this myself. To the ones who may need this in future:

```
$condition = '';
   $terms = explode(" ",$queryString);
   foreach($terms as $text)  
      {  
           $condition .= "name LIKE '%".($text)."%' OR ";  
      }  
      $condition = substr($condition, 0, -4); 
      $sql_query = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE " . $condition; 
      $result = DB::select($sql_query);
```

- condition is going to gather all the conditions to be searched.
- terms is going to collect all searches from the URL text is the
  invidual    items from the array.
- products is the name of the table.
- use DB;    should be initialized if you're in a different namespace.